# javax.naming.NoInitialContextException

Tags: java, jndi

getConnection Exception javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
null

when i run below code this is the exception i am getting.

I have already created respective jndi name connectionpools in glassfishv3
pl give  me any solution....

Thanks..

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    private static DataSource ds;

    private static Context initialContext = null;

    public static Connection getConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            initialContext = new InitialContext();
            ds = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("jdbc/__TimerPool");
            System.out.println("data source "+ds);

                return ds.getConnection();


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(("getConnection Exception " + e));
        }
        return null;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Test.getConnection());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ds = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("jdbc/__TimerPool");
```

ds = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/jdbc/__TimerPool");

**EDIT:** Sorry, "java:comp/env/jdbc/__TimerPool".

Comment: "Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial...." same exception saying this..

Comment: @MadhuB: so you aren't running this code in a container environment?

Comment: i am running it in glassfish3.1 environment